# How do get URLs in two languages indexed in Google?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, internationalization

I am about to put a website online having at least two languages: English (EN) and French (FR), each URL will be as follows:

- `example.com/fr/url...`
- `example.com/en/url...`

I have no idea what the correct settings are in Google Search Console to index internationalized URLs for each country. I also don't know how to write a robots.txt and sitemap.xml for this purpose.

Comment: See also: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization) and [How can I get search engines to crawl my site and see a localised view of my data?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2726/how-can-i-get-search-engines-to-crawl-my-site-and-see-a-localised-view-of-my-dat) and [Correctly handling multi language URL's in sitemaps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85099/correctly-handling-multi-language-urls-in-sitemaps)